# Storing and downloading pdf files from mongoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload

I am using NodeJs, mongoose, ejs

I want the user to be able to upload his CV (Less the 16 MB) as a pdf file, then the admin to be able to download the pdf or view the CV on the website.

[image: Review Applications page]

I did the upload part where I stored the cv like this in the database (which might be a wrong way):

```
cv: Object {
fileName: "Test Results All in testing-homework.pdf"
filePath: "cvs\1650985306448-.pdf"
fileType: "application/pdf"
}
```

and the pdf file is stored in the "/cvs" folder after upload.

I'm seeking a way to be able to download/view the pdf file from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use GridFs from mongodb.
refer:https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/gridfs/

**To Download from DB**

> ```
> bucket.openDownloadStreamByName('your_file_name').
>      pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./desired_name_of_output_file'));
> ```

Some of the Basic Upload and Download Operations using GridFs in MongoDB

> ```
> const mongoUrl='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db'
> const mongodb = require('mongodb');
> const fs = require('node:fs'); 
>
> const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(mongoUrl)
> const db = client.db('db');
> ```

**Create Bucket with user-defined name**

> ```
> const bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db,{bucketName:'name_of_bucket' });
> ```

**Upload to DB**

> ```
> fs.createReadStream('./filename.pdf').
>      pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('filename', {
>          chunkSizeBytes: 1048576,
>          metadata: { field: 'filename', value: 'myValue' }
>      }))
> ```

**Find**

> ```
> const cursor = bucket.find({});
> cursor.forEach(doc => console.log(doc));
> ```

**Delete**

> ```
> cursor.forEach(doc => bucket.delete(doc._id));
> ```